# How to get filename, filesize, date modified and store it

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, find, ls

I need to get the exact filepath, filesize, and date modified and store it in a mysql table.

If I do `ls` command, it gives me an output that is quite difficult to parse properly to be able to load it into a mysql table.

What would be the best way to get the filepath, size, and date modified and store it in a mysql table (currently, I am using `load data infile`).

Comment: You may want to mention which programming language/tool you're familiar with.

Comment: Mainly python, a very small amount of unix/shell stuff.

Comment: In that case: have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do all that stuff with the `stat` [command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).

For ex:

```
>$ stat -c "'%x' '%s'" robots.txt
'2013-01-28 16:13:48.000000000 -0800' '25'
```

You can then format them in a comma delimited file, and just read it with `LOAD DATA INFILE` as you mentioned it. For ex:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```